# Stacks - why PUSH and POP?

Tags: stack

I was wondering why we use the terms "push" and "pop" for adding/removing items from stacks? Is there some physical metaphor that caused those terms to be common?

The only suggestion I have is something like a [spring-loaded magazine for a handgun](http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/2645114/2/istockphoto_2645114_9mm_handgun_magazine.jpg), where rounds are "pushed" into it and can be "popped" out, but that seems a little unlikely.

A second stack trivia question: Why do most CPUs implement the call stack as growing **downwards** in memory, rather than upwards?

Comment: Actually, the 6502 and the 6800 are two notable, well-known CPUs that use "pull" to mean the opposite of "push".

Comment: Wasn't POP a mnemonic for "PULL OPERAND" on some old, obscure CPU?

Comment: The original terms used by Alan Turing in 1946 were bury and unbury - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type).

Comment: One of my lecturers used a Pez dispenser as an analogy.  Mainly to explain how a stack works, but I think it would work fairly well as an explanation of the terms.  Though I don't suppose this is the true etymology - indeed, I can't tell whether the timings would make sense for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the spring loaded stack of plates is correct, as the source for the term PUSH and POP.

In particular, the East Campus Commons Cafeteria at MIT had spring loaded stacks of plates in the 1957-1967 time frame.  The terms PUSH and POP would have been in use by the Tech Model Railroad Club.  I think this is the origin.

The Tech Model Railroad Club definitely influenced the design of the Digital Equipment Corporation's (DEC) PDP-6.  The PDP-6 was one of the first machines to have stack oriented instructions in the hardware.  The instructions were PUSH, POP, PUSHJ, POPJ.

http://ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/pdp-6.html#Special%20Features

Comment: Even if this in not possible to corroborate, it makes a great answer! Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to corroborate by looking into Alan Kotok's writings.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kotok

Comment: This would make sense, except the terminology wasn't invented at MIT. It was the great [Friedrich Bauer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_L._Bauer) circa 1951 who described a "pushdown" system, based on Turing's concepts (Turing used the terms "bury" and "unbury"). Bauer also gave us the term *software engineering*, and he's still with us. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, actual history should certainly trump presumed history, assuming you are correct.  Do you have a source for Bauer's use of "pushdown"?  What is the phrase in German?

Comment: @WalterMitty: Haven't found the paper yet. Found a few sources, such as [this one](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=y4uTaLiN-wQC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=Bauer+pushdown&source=bl&ots=MiAvd_yVyj&sig=TLTd0GfodplGKoUvj5G-pUOygng&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sCtEVKT-LuPY7AbnzICwDQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Bauer%20pushdown&f=false).

Comment: Good enough.  And there is the possibility, admittedly slight, that the same phrase was independently invented multiple times before the ideas coalesced.  I credit MIT with a role in advancing the usage of stacks due to the work of John McCarthy, inventor of LISP.

Answer (score 22):

For your second question, Wikipedia has an article about the CS philosophy that controls the stack:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO

And for the first, also on wikipedia:

> A frequently used metaphor is the idea
>   of a stack of plates in a spring
>   loaded cafeteria stack. In such a
>   stack, only the top plate is visible
>   and accessible to the user, all other
>   plates remain hidden. As new plates
>   are added, each new plate becomes the
>   top of the stack, hiding each plate
>   below, pushing the stack of plates
>   down. As the top plate is removed from
>   the stack, they can be used, the
>   plates pop back up, and the second
>   plate becomes the top of the stack.
>   Two important principles are
>   illustrated by this metaphor: the Last
>   In First Out principle is one; the
>   second is that the contents of the
>   stack are hidden. Only the top plate
>   is visible, so to see what is on the
>   third plate, the first and second
>   plates will have to be removed. This
>   can also be written as FILO-First In
>   Last Out, i.e. the record inserted
>   first will be popped out at last.

Comment: I've seen a lot more gun and rifle magazines than I've seen cafeterias with that sort of spring loaded stack.

Comment: Same. But I find it easier to imagine because I haven't ever handled a gun. :P

Comment: I like the cafeteria plate stack, but the wikipedia link you give doesn't much answer my second question.

Comment: We had them at my college's dining hall. Sometimes too many plates were stacked and they can no longer be pushed down.  As a result, more than the top plate became visible... [CONTINUE]

Comment: ...These top plates became poorly balanced with nothing holding tightly them in place making them very unstable.  Someone can quite easily knock them over breaking them. Keeping with the analogy...a stack overflow.

Comment: I've seen LIFO more often than FILO.

Comment: IIRC, at the MIT cafeteria, there were four posts extending upward from counter level that kept the stack of plates stable even if it extended slightly from the counter top.

Answer (score 14):

For the second question: Assembler programmers on small systems tend to write code that begins at low addresses in memory, and grow to higher addresses as more code is added.

Because of this, making a stack grow downward allows you to start the stack at the top of physical memory and allow the two memory zones to grow towards each other.  This simplifies memory management in this sort of trivial environment.

Even in a system with segregated ROM/RAM fixed data allocations are easiest to build from the bottom up and thus replace the code portion of the above explanation.

While such trivial memory schemes are very rare anymore, the hardware practice continues as established.

Answer (score 7):

Re your "second trivial question": I've seen considerable inconsistency in defining what "up" and "down" mean! From early days, some manufacturers and authors drew memory diagrams with low addresses at the top of the page (presumably mimicking the order in which a page is read), while others put high addresses at the top of the page (presumably mimicking graph paper coordinates or the floors in a building).

Of course the concept of a stack (and the concept of addressable memory as well) is independent of such visual metaphors. One can implement a stack which "grows" in either direction. In fact, I've often seen the trick below (in bare-metal level implementations) used to share a region of memory between two stacks:

```
+---+---+--------   -------+--+--+--+
|   |   |   ->   ...   <-  |  |  |  |
+---+---+--------   -------+--+--+--+
^                                   ^
Stack 1      both stacks      Stack 2
base        "grow" toward        base
              the middle
```

So my answer is that stacks conceptually *never* grow either "downward" or "upward" but simply grow from their base. An individual stack may be *implemented* in either direction (or in *neither* direction, if it's using a linked representation with garbage collection, in which case the elements may be *anywhere* in nodespace).

Comment: Thanks. I was specifically referring to the hardware *implementation* of call stacks in CPUs growing from higher to lower memory addresses (= downwards!)

Comment: To me, stacks always conceptually grow up: the most recently added item is always deemed the TOP of the stack. You can't push things onto the bottom, or else it'd be a queue (except that queues don't have tops or bottoms). Whether addresses increase or decrease while approaching the top is separate.

Answer (score 6):

Think of it like a pez dispenser.  You can push a new one on top.  And then pop it off the top.

That is always what I think of when I think push and pop. (Probably not very historical though)

**Are you asking yourself what the heck are PEZ?**  See the comments.

Comment: ... uh, whats a pez dispenser?

Comment: I've always seen it as a Pez dispenser too. +1 for the analogy

Comment: http://images.google.com/images?client=safari&rls=en-us&q=pez+dispenser&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&um=1&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&resnum=4&ct=title

Comment: Pez is(are) one of my favorite candies!

Comment: It's a yank thing, I've haven't seen Pez anywhere in europe, only the states. Stephen King regularly references Pez when writing about Kids back in the days when he was young http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEZ

Comment: @Roddy: PEZ dispensers work similar to your spring-loaded magazine, except with candy. PEZ is a brand of candy that's sold with dispensers; the dispensers usually have a top shaped like cartoon characters' heads and can be collectors items.

Comment: @Binary - "only in the states"?  PEZ is an Austrian company!

Comment: No they did have PEZ in the UK, I remember seeing it in the shops. I think it just wasn't quite as popular.

Comment: pretty popular in Bulgaria ;]

Comment: Ditto for Australia. I remember them as being more acid/tart in my youth. These days they seem sweeter.

Answer (score 5):

Alliteration is always attractive (see what I did there?), and these words are short, alliterative, and suggestive.  The same goes for the old BASIC commands peek and poke, which have the extra advantage of the parallel k's.

A common physical metaphor is a cafeteria plate dispenser, where a spring-loaded stack of plates makes it so that you can take a plate off the top, but the next plate rises to be in the same position.

Comment: Not technically alliteration as alliteration is the repetition of the same starting _consonant_ sound http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliteration

Comment: What do you know! I learn something new every day.  I can't find a word that means the same thing for vowels, I wonder why?

Answer (score 2):

The answers on [this page](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/usenet/embedded/show/79584-1.php) pretty much answer the stack direction question. If I had to sum it up, I would say it is done downwards to remain consistent with ancient computers.

Comment: Anybody rememeber the 6502?  The hardware stack was in one code page (page 1, I think) so it was limited to 256 bytes.

Comment: I do :) My first assembler - 6502 had 3 registers (A, X, Y), plus stack, 1st page (00-FF) was for indexing w/ Y (mostly) and X (but hardly) and the second (100-1FF) was the stack. Back in the day writing in the code directly was the standard way of memory iteration unless using the zero page addresses (and they were precious)

Answer (score 0):

I think the original story came about because of some developers seeing the plate stack (like you often see in buffet restaurants).  You pushed a new plate on to the top of the stack, and you popped one off the top as well.

Answer (score 0):

As to stacks growing downwards in memory, remember that When dealing with hierarchical data structures (trees), most programmers are happy to draw one on a page with the base (or trunk) at the top of the page...

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is really old, but I have a thought about the second question:

In my mind, the stack grows up, even though the memory addresses decrease. If you were to write a whole bunch of numbers on a piece of paper, you would start at the top left, with 0. Then you would increase the numbers going left to right, then top to bottom. So say the stack is like this:

```
000 001 002 003 004     000 001 002 003 004     000 001 002 003 004
005 006 007 008 009     005 006 007 008 009     005 006 007 008 009
010 011 012 013 014     010 011 012 013 014     010 011 012 013 014
015 016 017 018 019     015 016 017 018 019     015 016 017 018 019
020 021 022 023 024     020 021 022 023 024     020 021 022 023 024
025 026 027 028 029     025 026 027 028 029     025 026 027 028 029
```

where the bold numbers represent stack memory, and unbold numbers represent memory addresses which the stack is not using. Each block of the same numbers represents a stage of a program where the call stack has grown.

Even though the memory addresses are moving downward, the stack is growing upwards.

Similarly, with the spring loaded plate stack,
if you took a plate off the top of the stack, you would call that the first plate (smallest number) right? Even thought it is the highest up. A programmer might even call it the zeroth plate.

Comment: Similarly, if you write out the machine code at the beginning of virtual memory of a process or the permanent memory of the program the way you would normally write text in most writing systems, you would put the earlier instructions above the later instructions (as if your eyes were falling down the page as you read). I believe this means putting lower-numbered addresses above higher-numbered addresses in most implementations, especially since I think CPUs are usually optimized to INCREMENT the program counter after performing an instruction.

Answer (score 0):

For the question of why do stacks grow down, I would imagine it is used to save memory.

If you start from the top of the stack memory (the highest value addresses) and work down to zero, I assume its easier to check if you have reached address `$0x00000000` than allocating a variable to give you the maximum height of the stack and checking whether or not you have reached that address.

I assume this makes it easier to check if you're reaching the end of your addressable space as no matter how much memory is available the limit of the stack is always going to be `$0x00000000`.